# Convert Uint16Array containing 8-bit integers to regular integer

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, binary-data, typed-arrays

How do you convert following

```
var data = new Uint16Array([131, 220]);
```

to `integer`? Expected value is somewhere around `970`

Comment: *"Expected value is somewhere around `970`"* How did you arrive at that value?

Comment: From https://github.com/otland/forgottenserver/blob/cc8e15e9166359faa52d38823e679355a615ab23/src/protocollogin.cpp#L141 and I know value should be something between 1090 and 1098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to reduce the values by multiplying with 2<sup>8</sup> and cut off the first bit.

(This is not a general converting, but rather for this special purpose.)

```js
var data = new Uint16Array([131, 220]),
    value = [].reduce.call(data, function (r, a) {
        return (r << 8) + a;
    }, 0) & ((1 << 15) - 1);

console.log(value);
```

Comment: is a general converting mechanism possible, no matter the number of digits?

Comment: @Arrow, actually no, because it is a special case. you may test it for other data, but it should not work, as i it see.